# Redirect to home page after event.preventDefault..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this on my angularjs script file inside the controller.

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $location.url("/");
});
```

It works partially not actually how I want it to work. This code prevents page reload by asking stay on the page or not. If a user still wants to reload the page by clicking Leave page I want to redirect to the home page of my angular app. I tried several codes but none of them didn't seem to work. Has anyone an answer for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try the ```confirm``` js method? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: I did and it didn't work either

Comment: do this instead of $location.url -> `$window.location.href = '/';`

Comment: tried that as well... :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are in a controller and you have a `$scope` variable

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")) {
        $location.url("/");
    }
});
```

this should work, let me know (first of all if i understood your question)

Comment: now it ask if you need to leave on every link click. Don't want that. Just on Reloads